# NetsSuite parallel approval workflow

Tags: netsuite

I have made some basic approval workflows for custom records and things like estimates, but they have all been single approver or sequential. Does anyone have some advice on how I might achieve a parallel/asynchronous approval workflow?

I figured the workflow would add the approvers to a workflow variable list, send out an email to each approver and as the emails came back it would remove the people from another list awaiting approval. Once the list was empty it would transition to the next state. Seems like a simple concept but I can't get a workflow to add multiple items to a list...just set a static value which is 1 employee.

Thoughts?

Comment: There are a couple of ways (at least) to do this. What is the source of the approvers? How are they chosen based on the record to be approved? Do all approvers need to approve to move forward or are there some 'super-approvers' whose approval will kick the record to the next step?

Comment: It's basically departmental approves. So if an HR field is filled out, HR will become an approver. All approvers have to respond, with no super approvers. I like your custom record suggestion and will give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more detail it's difficult to give detailed answers but something like the following is the idea:

You'll probably need a custom record that is linked as a child to the record to be approved.
Some workflow action scripts will likely be required to get this working.

When the main record enters the approval state a workflow action script will get the list of approvers and for each create a custom (approval) record linking the approver, approval status and record to be approved.

Another workflow will handle the single record approval of the new approvals record (e.g. sending out the original notice email, cancelling the workflow if the parent is rejected)

A scheduled transition on the main workflow will run searches to transition the main record when all approval records are approved or any approval record is rejected.